# Question regarding general solution, particular solution and homogenous solution

Tags: linear-algebra

If the solution set of a system of equations is only a particular solution then can I automatically claim that the solution of the associated homogenous system will be the zero vector.

In other words is it possible for the solution set of a system of equations be a particular solution and the solution of the homogenous be anything other than zero? Such that the general solution (particular + homogenous) is not just the particular solution.

Comment: Can you provide an example to what you're referring? Is the system linear? nonlinear? A little more info may be helpful.

Comment: By particular solution do you mean unique solution?

Comment: @fwd yes, I meant that

Comment: @Gregory sure, i'll expand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the solution of the homogeneous can only be $0$. Suppose $\vec{x_0}$ is the unique solution of $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ but there is a non-zero solution of $A\vec{x} = 0$, say $y_0$. Then $\vec{x_0} + \vec{y_0} \ne \vec{x_0}$ is also a solution of $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$, which says that the solution $x_0$ is not unique.

Comment: perfect, just what I wanted.